# ssh password authentication for one user, public key for other user

Tags: security, ssh, server, command-line-interface

I know of the option

```
PasswordAuthentication yes
```

inside `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. Is it possible to set this per user?
My goal is to have one user with root privileges to only login with a public key, not through a password. And another user with lower privileges to login with a password, not requiring a public key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`sshd_config`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?sshd_config(5)) includes the option `Match`, which allows to start a conditional block

```
Match User user1
PasswordAuthentication yes
Match all
Other rules
```

You can add different conditional rules that way.
For instance, allow only user1, from a specific IP:

```
Match Address 192.168.1.20
AllowUsers user1
```

Once you have modified the sshd_config:

```
systemctl restart sshd
systemctl status sshd
```

And you can test your setup.